# Column File Format Stream

Tags: c++, c++17

### What I want to Build

I need to store structured data in a file column format. i.e. Each row of data is split across multiple files, each file representing one specific data item.

Example:

```
class Team {
    int id;
    int size;
};
class Person {
     std::string   name;
     int           age;
     double        salary;
     Team.         team;
}
```

If I saved this to a file it would generate one row with three columns (name/age/salary/team (team will have its own two columns)). But each column is stored in its own file.

#### Example:

```
CF::File.    saveFile("data");
saveFile << Person{"Loki", 33, 12345, Team{12,34}};
saveFile << Person{"Tom",  25, 34566, Team{13,34}};
saveFile << Person{"Luke", 45, 43125, Team{14,34}};
saveFile << Person{"John", 32, 43895, Team{15,34}};
saveFile << Person{"Pete", 18, 43111, Team{16,34}};
```

This should generate three files, each file with 5 values:

```
> find data
data/name
data/age
data/salary
data/team/id
data/team/size
```

Currently it does not generate indexes into these files (but this may be a later addition).

### Building

I reuse code (The Traits) from ThorsSerializer (reviewed here [Macro to build type declaration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81922/macro-to-build-type-declaration) )

If you want to build this code you will need to have a local copy of [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer). The easiest way to get a copy is via **brew** (or a header only version can be retrieved via git).

```
 Brew: installed (and removed) via brew `brew install thors-serializer`.  
 Git:  git clone --single-branch --branch header-only https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer.git
```

### Things I think could be better.

1. Constructors.
   Seems like a lot of duplication between the move and copy constructors. Not sure best way to deal with this.
2. Recursive template expansion.
   I use `{0, (<expression>, 0)...}` to expand tuples open to more elegant alternatives.

Why:

```
int ignore = {0, (<expression>, 0)...};
((void)ignore);

/*
 *  {0,   This zero is for the situation where the Args... pack is empty
 *        Without this case an empty parameter pack causes a compilation failure.
 *
 *  , 0)  This allows me to use void expressions and the comma
 *        operator results in the zero result of the ( <exp>, 0)
 *
 * Then we assign to a single int as this reduces the initialization
 * a comma expression list of all zeros.
 *
 * Then we have to use the variable in an expression otherwise the
 * compiler will complain. So just cast to void which is a no-op.
 */
```

### Source

#### File.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_FS_COLUMNFORMAT_FILE_H
#define THORSANVIL_FS_COLUMNFORMAT_FILE_H

#include <ThorSerialize/Traits.h>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <fstream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace FS
    {
        namespace ColumnFormat
        {

template<typename T>
class File;

template<typename T, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::TraitType type = ThorsAnvil::Serialize::Traits<T>::type>
struct FileTupleColumn;

template<typename T>
struct FileTupleColumn<T, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::TraitType::Value>
{
    using ColumnType  = std::ofstream;
};
template<typename T>
struct FileTupleColumn<T, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::TraitType::Map>
{
    using ColumnType  = File<T>;
};

template<typename T, typename P>
struct FileTupleColumnBuilder;

template<typename T, typename P>
struct FileTupleColumnBuilder<T, std::pair<char const*, P T::*>>
{
    using ColumnType = typename FileTupleColumn<P>::ColumnType;
};
template<typename T, typename TUP>
struct FileTupleBuilderFromArgs;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct FileTupleBuilderFromArgs<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    using FileTuple = std::tuple<typename FileTupleColumnBuilder<T, Args>::ColumnType...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct FileTupleBuilderFromObj
{
    using Traits    = ThorsAnvil::Serialize::Traits<T>;
    using FileTuple = typename FileTupleBuilderFromArgs<T, typename Traits::Members>::FileTuple;
};

template<typename T>
class File
{
    using FileTuple = typename FileTupleBuilderFromObj<T>::FileTuple;

    bool            fileOpened;
    std::string     baseFileName;
    FileTuple       fileTuple;

    public:
        File(std::string&& fileName = "");
        File(std::string const&  fileName);
        ~File();

        void open(std::string const& fileName);
        void open(std::string&& fileName);
        void open();
        void close();

        void write(T const& data);

        friend File& operator<<(File& file, T const& data) {
            file.write(data);
            return file;
        }
        template<std::size_t I, typename F, typename M>
        void writeOneMember(F& files, M& members, T const& data);

        template<typename F, typename M, std::size_t... I>
        void writeMembers(F& files, M& member, T const& data, std::index_sequence<I...> const&);
    private:
        using Traits    = ThorsAnvil::Serialize::Traits<T>;
        using Members   = typename Traits::Members;
        using Index     = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Members>::value>;

        void doOpen();
        void doClose();

        template<std::size_t... I>
        void doCloseMembers(std::index_sequence<I...> const&);

        template<std::size_t... I>
        void doOpenMembers(std::index_sequence<I...> const&);
};

        }
    }
}

#endif
```

#### File.tpp

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_FS_COLUMNFORMAT_FILE_TPP
#define THORSANVIL_FS_COLUMNFORMAT_FILE_TPP

#include "file.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace FS
    {
        namespace ColumnFormat
        {

template<typename T>
File<T>::File(std::string&& fileName)
    : fileOpened(false)
    , baseFileName(std::move(fileName))
{
    open();
}

template<typename T>
File<T>::File(std::string const& fileName)
    : fileOpened(false)
    , baseFileName(std::move(fileName))
{
    open();
}

template<typename T>
File<T>::~File()
{}

template<typename T>
void File<T>::open(std::string const& fileName)
{
    if (fileOpened) {
        return;
    }
    baseFileName = fileName;
    open();
}


template<typename T>
void File<T>::open(std::string&& fileName)
{
    if (fileOpened) {
        return;
    }
    baseFileName = std::move(fileName);
    open();
}

template<typename T>
void File<T>::open()
{
    if (baseFileName == "") {
        return;
    }
    doOpen();
    fileOpened = true;
}

template<typename T>
void File<T>::close()
{
    if (!fileOpened) {
        return;
    }
    doClose();
    fileOpened = false;
}

template<typename T>
template<std::size_t... I>
void File<T>::doCloseMembers(std::index_sequence<I...> const&)
{
    int ignore =
    {
        0, ([&fileTuple = this->fileTuple](){std::get<I>(fileTuple).close();}(), 0)...
    };
    ((void)ignore);
}

template<typename T>
template<std::size_t... I>
void File<T>::doOpenMembers(std::index_sequence<I...> const&)
{
    int ignore =
    {
        0,
        (
            [&baseFileName = this->baseFileName, &fileTuple = this->fileTuple]()
            {
                auto& members   = Traits::getMembers();
                auto& name      = std::get<I>(members).first;
                auto& file      = std::get<I>(fileTuple);

                mkdir(baseFileName.c_str(), 0777);
                std::string     fileNamePath(baseFileName);
                fileNamePath += "/";
                fileNamePath += name;

                file.open(fileNamePath);
            }(),
            0
        )...
    };
    ((void)ignore);
}

template<typename T>
void File<T>::doOpen()
{
    doOpenMembers(Index{});
}

template<typename T>
void File<T>::doClose()
{
    doCloseMembers(Index{});
}
template<typename F, typename T, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::TraitType type = ThorsAnvil::Serialize::Traits<T>::type>
struct FileWriter
{
    void write(F& file, T const& obj)
    {
        file << obj;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct FileWriter<std::ofstream, T, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::TraitType::Value>
{
    void write(std::ostream& file, T const& obj)
    {
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&obj), sizeof obj);
    }
};

template<>
struct FileWriter<std::ofstream, std::string, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::TraitType::Value>
{
    void write(std::ostream& file, std::string const& obj)
    {
        std::string::const_iterator start   = std::begin(obj);
        std::size_t                 used    = 0;

        for(std::size_t size = obj.find('\n'); size != std::string::npos; size = obj.find('\n', size + 1))
        {
            size = (size == std::string::npos) ? (std::end(obj) - start) : size;
            std::size_t len = (size - used);
            file << std::string_view(&*start, size - used) << '\0';

            start += (len + 1);
            used  += (len + 1);
        }
        file << std::string_view(&*start) << "\n";
    }
};

template<typename P>
struct GetPointerType;

template<typename R, typename T>
struct GetPointerType<std::pair<char const*, R T::*>>
{
    using ReturnType = R;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename F, typename M, std::size_t... I>
void File<T>::writeMembers(F& files, M& members, T const& data, std::index_sequence<I...> const&)
{
    auto ignore =
    {   0,
        (
            [&files, &members, &data]()
            {
                auto& file          = std::get<I>(files);
                auto& pointer       = std::get<I>(members).second;

                using File          = typename std::tuple_element<I, F>::type;
                using PointerType   = typename std::tuple_element<I, Members>::type;
                using Dst           = typename GetPointerType<PointerType>::ReturnType;

                FileWriter<File, Dst>    fileWriter;
                fileWriter.write(file, data.*pointer);
            }(),
            0
        )...
    };
    ((void)ignore);
}

template<typename T>
void File<T>::write(T const& data)
{
    writeMembers(fileTuple, Traits::getMembers(), data, Index{});
}
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

#### Main.cpp

A test application to make sure it works.

```
#include "file.h"
#include "file.tpp"

#include <ThorSerialize/Traits.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    int         age;
};

struct Employee
{
    Person      p;
    double      salary;
};

ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Person, name, age);
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Employee, p, salary);

namespace CF = ThorsAnvil::FS::ColumnFormat;

int main()
{
    CF::File<Person>    file1("data1");
    CF::File<Employee>  file2("data2");
    std::cout << "H World\n";

    file1 << Person{"Martin", 12};
    file2 << Employee{Person{"KK", 14}, 2.34};
}
```

#### Makefile

```
SRC         = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ         = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC))

CXXFLAGS▸   += -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unknown-pragmas $(EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR)

all:        $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o file $(OBJ)
```

If you installed `ThorsSerializer` via brew this should work as-is. If you used the header-only version of git then you will need to add a line to this file:

```
EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR  = <Dir where you cloned from>/ThorsSerializer
```

Comment: Is "Formst" in the title a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some random thoughts here:

## Structure

It is a bit surprising that I need to include `file.tpp` to get the definition of templates.  The confusion may be reduced by either making `file.h` include `file.tpp`, or renaming `file.h` to something like `file_fwd.h`.

## Interface

Do you really need open and closed states?  The implementation is simpler if the closed state is not supported (i.e., streams open at construction and close at destruction).  Then, you can drop `open` and `close`, as well as the `fileOpened` member.

The public function `writeMembers` has an `std::index_sequence` parameter.  I guess keeping it parallel to `writeOneMember` is cleaner:

```
template <std::size_t    I, typename F, typename M>
void writeOneMember(F& files, M& members, T const& data);

template <std::size_t... I, typename F, typename M>
void   writeMembers(F& files, M& members, T const& data);
```

(Also I don't think you need to pass empty types like `std::index_sequence` by const reference.)

## Implementation

> ```
> File(std::string&& fileName = "");
> File(std::string const&  fileName);
> ~File();
> ```

I don't think you need the destructor — it's just `{}` after all.  The two constructors can also be merged, thanks to `std::string` supporting move semantics: (I )

```
File(std::string fileName = {})
    : baseFileName{std::move(fileName)}
{
    open();
}
```

I'm surprised that assigning a braced-init-list to a scalar even compiles ([I can't get that to compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TEtMCu6h2N99bNMu)).  Anyway, you don't need them — fold expressions are simpler:

```
(expression, ...);
```

Also, the capture of many lambdas may be simplified to just `[&]` (unless you really want to be explicit; I wouldn't for immediately invoked lambdas like this).

Comment: Thanks for that. Quesiton about the constructor. K I see how you can simplify the case for `std::string` because we know that it has move semantics. But what about a constructor for a generic class that takes a template parameter in the constructor. In that case we can not tell if T has a move constructor but writing this way would force a non movable object to be copied twice. Is there a generic way of writing the constructor that would work?

Comment: @MartinYork For generic types, we can use perfect forwarding, which allows us to collect arguments and defer construction.  This is the usual approach taken by the standard library (`emplace`, `optional(in_place)`, etc.).  If list initialization semantics is needed, users can `forward_as_tuple` and make a wrapper that automatically converts to the destination type.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/whOHW6kcmm601GiY